# Vertical align kable's column name

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

Suppose the next example:

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10)

names(df) <- c("This is a looooooong title, I don't know how to handle this... Also, I'm trying to extend this title even more... This column name will be used to compute vertical space","I want to align vectically this column name")

df %>% kable(format = 'latex', linesep = "", align = 'c') %>% kable_styling(full_width = T)
```

[image]

How can align vertically the second column name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an easier way, but you can go with the `multirow` package:

````
---
title: "Test Book"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multirow}
author: "therimalaya"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

# Hello World


```{r, error = TRUE, echo = T}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10)
names(df) <- c("This is a looooooong title, I don't know how to handle this... Also, I'm trying to extend this title even more... This column name will be used to compute vertical space","\\multirow{1}{*}[0pt]{I want to align vectically this column name}")

df %>% kable(format = 'latex', linesep = "", align = 'c', escape = F) %>% kable_styling(full_width = T)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

As of [August 2020](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/425), The `column_spec()` function in the `kableExtra` package has a `latex_valign` argument. This only works if you also specify the column width, so it's not compatible with `kable_styling(full_width = T)`

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10)

names(df) <- c("This is a looooooong title, I don't know how to handle this... Also, I'm trying to extend this title even more... This column name will be used to compute vertical space","I want to align vectically this column name")

  df %>% kable(
        linesep = "",
        align = "c",
        format = "latex") %>% 
  column_spec(1:2, 
              width = "3in", 
              latex_valign = "m")
```