# Vertically align column name using kable and rendering with rmarkdown into html

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

Created the table below and would like to vertically align the word "Species" in the center/middle of the cell. I am using `RMarkdown` to generate the HTML not LateX. Any tips?

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE )


library( kableExtra )
options( scipen = 99 )

```

```{r iris}

tab_iris <- knitr::kable( iris , format = "html" , col.names = c( "Sepal<br>Length" , "Sepal<br>Width" , "Petal<br>Length" , "Petal<br>Width" , "Species" ) , align = "c" , escape = F ) %>% kable_styling(full_width = F , bootstrap_options = c( 'hover', 'condensed' , 'bordered'), position = 'left') %>% add_header_above( c('Kendal Iris Test' = 5) , bold = TRUE , background = '#0077c8' , color = 'white' ) 

```

`r tab_iris`
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RMarkdown kable vertically align cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143690/rmarkdown-kable-vertically-align-cells)

Comment: @M-- sadly no. Need to make the edit with HTML formatting, not LateX.

Comment: There's a second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597846/6461462

Comment: ```kable( iris , format = "html" , 
              col.names = c( "Sepal<br>Length" , "Sepal<br>Width" , "Petal<br>Length" , "Petal<br>Width" , "Species" ) , 
              align = "c" , escape = F ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F , bootstrap_options = c( 'hover', 'condensed' , 'bordered'), position = 'left') %>% 
  add_header_above( c('Kendal Iris Test' = 5) , bold = TRUE , background = '#0077c8' , color = 'white' ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = T) %>% 
  row_spec(0 ,  bold = T, extra_css = 'vertical-align: middle !important;')```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `kableExtra::row_specs` and its `extra_css` argument:

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable( head(iris) , format = "html" , 
       col.names = c( "Sepal<br>Length" , "Sepal<br>Width" , 
                      "Petal<br>Length" , "Petal<br>Width" , "Species" ) , 
       align = "c" , escape = F ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F , bootstrap_options = c( 'hover', 'condensed' , 'bordered'), 
                                 position = 'left') %>% 
  add_header_above( c('Kendal Iris Test' = 5) , bold = TRUE , 
                    background = '#0077c8' , color = 'white' ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = T) %>% 
  row_spec(0 ,  bold = F, extra_css = 'vertical-align: middle !important;')
```

[image]